# Access Virtual Machine via PuTTY Using Built-in Command "vagrant ssh"

Tags: ssh, putty, vagrant

I have installed Vagrant, PuTTY, PuTTYgen and Virtual Box and I now want to 
open a SSH connection to my virtual machine with the windows command prompt.

Every time I want to open the connection with the `vagrant ssh`command I get this error:

```
vagrant ssh
`ssh` executable not found in any directories in the %PATH% variable. Is an
SSH client installed? Try installing Cygwin, MinGW or Git, all of which
contain an SSH client. Or use the PuTTY SSH client with the following
authentication information shown below:
```

I already know about the possibility to install "Git" to solve this problem!

I was wondering if its possible to use PuTTY in combination with the command `vagrant ssh` instead of OpenSSH!

For example:

With a batch file or something to ajust the syntaxes.

Comment: Are you trying to access a vagrant box which is hosted on a remote machine?

Comment: It is on my own computer.
Solved it with the Multi-Putty-Plugin,
which is very easy to find with Google.
Thanks a lot for the fast help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an official thread for Vagrant [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/933) which ended in no result AFAIR. But when googling for "vagrant putty" there seem to exist many plugins for Vagrant bringing that functionality, maybe through "hacks".

For reference: [vagrant-multi-putty](https://github.com/nickryand/vagrant-multi-putty). Worked for me too on Windows after two simple commands: `vagrant plugin install vagrant-multi-putty` and `vagrant putty` (only for Vagrant 1.1 and newer),

Comment: Directly found the "Multi-Putty-Plugin". Worked fine within minutes. thanks.

Comment: At first, I mistakenly did not download the putty binary(http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) as specified in the docs(https://github.com/nickryand/vagrant-multi-putty) for vagrant-mulit-putty. After downloading putty and adding it to my windows system PATH, the plugin worked perfectly.